# Firebase post запрос

Tags: java, http, post, okhttp

Добрые день. Формирую запрос в Firebase API через okhttp либу кодом:

```
JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
    data.put("event", "goChat");

    String[] registration_ids = {"client token firebase"};
    JSONObject protocol = new JSONObject();
    protocol.put("registration_ids", registration_ids); //
    protocol.put("data", data);

    MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, protocol.toString());

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(urlFirebaseApi)
            .addHeader("Content-type", "application/json")
            .addHeader("Authorization:key=", MY_APP_FB_KEY)
            .post(body)
            .build();

     Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

Получаю пост запрос вида(ловлю его модулем Apache на тестовом сервере):

```
    --0e16940d-A--
[26/Feb/2018:19:39:32 +0600] WpQOFH8AAQEAAGkSlzcAAAAB 192.168.1.2 55161 192.168.1.30 80
--0e16940d-B--
POST / HTTP/1.1
content-type: application/json
Authorization: key=: AAAAzX_mvfQ:APA91bE1Y-1ao......... MY APP FB KEY
Content-Length: 306
Host: 192.168.1.30
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip
User-Agent: okhttp/3.10.0

--0e16940d-C--
{"data":{"event":"goChat"}, "registration_ids":["client token FB there"]}
--0e16940d-F--
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Length: 276
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
--0e16940d-E--
```

И https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send отвечает code=400, что говорит об ошибке парсинга данных json. Ладно думаю я. Делаю скрипт на пхп, пробую отправить запрос на Api с помощью CURL.
Код PHP:

```
$fields = array (
    'registration_ids' => array (
        "MY_TOKEN_DB"
    ),
    'data' => array (
        "event" => $event,
    )
);
$fields = json_encode ( $fields );

$headers = array (
    'Authorization: key=' . "MY_APP_FB_KEY",
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);

$myCurl = curl_init ();
curl_setopt ( $myCurl, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt ( $myCurl, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt ( $myCurl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt ( $myCurl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt ( $myCurl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields );

$result = curl_exec ( $myCurl );
curl_close ( $myCurl );
```

Тело запроса, также отловленное с помощью мода апача:

```
[26/Feb/2018:19:35:09 +0600] WpQNDX8AAQEAAGkUxeAAAAAD 192.168.1.30 51266 192.168.1.30 80
--29939b3b-B--
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.30
Accept: */*
Authorization: key=MY_APP_KEY_FB
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 362

--29939b3b-C--
{"registration_ids":["CLIENT_TOKEN_FB"],
"data":{"event":"goChat"}}
--29939b3b-F--
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Length: 276
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

И все срабатывает! Бьюсь уже три часа и не пойму. В POST запросах понимаю слабо, надеюсь кто-то пояснит, благодарен заранеею

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы неверно указываете заголовок для запроса. Имя заголовка идёт до двоеточия, значение - после. Т.е. должно быть так:

```
.addHeader("Authorization", "key=" + MY_APP_FB_KEY)
```

Comment: Спасибо, действительно, все заработало. А хотя все равно response говорит что ошибка парсинга, но все работает.

Answer (score 1):

Если httpok не принципиально, то попробуй RestAssured, вот так примерно должно работать

```
import static com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured.config;
import static com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured.given;

    String[] registration_ids = {"client token firebase"};
    String url = "https://";
    Response response = given()
            .headers("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .headers("Authorization:key=", MY_APP_FB_KEY)
            .when()
            .body(new JSONObject().put("registration_ids", registration_ids)
                    .put("data", new JSONObject().put("event", "goChat").toString()).toString())
            .post(url);
```

или так мб проще:

```
import static com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured.config;
import static com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured.given;
        String[] registration_ids = {"client token firebase"};
        String url = "https://";

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    jsonObject.put("registration_ids", registration_ids);
    jsonObject.put("data", new JSONObject().put("event", "goChat").toString());


    Response response = given()
            .headers("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .headers("Authorization:key=", MY_APP_FB_KEY)
            .when()
            .body(jsonObject.toString())
            .post(url);
```